# Call an method in jni

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Hi i have the following problem in my android studio

root.cpp:

```
int getRoot(char *argv[])
{
    char ml[64];
    sprintf(ml,"su -c %s",*argv);
    if (getuid() != 0)
    {
        system(ml);
        exit(1);//Exit the process without root
    }
}
```

root.h:

```
int getRoot(char *argv[]);
```

Now how can i call this method in native-lib.cpp
i tried with

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_root_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    getRoot(char *argv[]);
}
```

but i get error in `*argv[]`
can someone help me please?

Comment: must be something like this `getRoot(argv);` But what's `argv` here?

Comment: i dont really know what iam trying since some days is give root permission to my native code for Vm_read but i dont know i gives root by java but its not working for jni so i found this code but i dont know how to call it

Comment: with getRoot(argv) is not working too

Comment: Obviously you cannot call it with something you don't have. What do you _want_ the string array to contain?

Comment: what i just want is give root access to my native code

Comment: The `su` command will start *another* process as root. Your current native code will not magically get root access.

Comment: so what is the solution now my problem is that in my c code i need to get some ouputs from c and use it in java and i also need to send an integer from my java code to the c++ code

Comment: You need to rethink your architecture. You have written complicated JNI code that is no more powerful or useful than `java.lang.Runtime.exec(...)`

Comment: That us the problem my jni code is working 100% but i need to give it root permission but to the whole jni not woth command and i dont got it to now